# How to model topics and partitions for Kafka when used to store all business events?

Tags: apache-kafka

We're considering using Kafka as a way to store all our business events forever. The purpose is to be able to spin up new "microservices" that we haven't yet thought of that will be able to leverage on all previous events to build up their projections/state. Another use case might be an existing service where we'd like to "replay" all events that is of interest to this service to recreate its state.

Note that we're not planning to use Kafka as an "event store" in the sense that events will be projected/loaded into an aggregate on "every request".

Also (as far as I can tell) we don't know how consumers will consume the events. A new microservice might need all sorts of different events in order to create its internal projection/state.

1. Is Kafka suitable for this or is there a better alternative?
2. If so, what's a good way to model this (topics/partitions)?
3. We're currently using RabbitMQ for messaging (business events are sent to RabbitMQ). It would be great if we could migrate away from RabbitMQ in the future and move entirely to Kafka. I assume that this could change the way topics and partitions are modelled since now we have a better understanding of how consumers will consume the events. Would this be compatible with the other use case (infinite retention and replay)?

Comment: How did this shake out for you? Did you use Kafka for this? I touched on some of these subjects here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482974/741970

Answer (score 2):

This is very good that you are switching to **KAFKA** and Yes it is possible to keep data in KAFKA BROKERs but i would suggest rather than keeping all the data in **KAFKA-BROKERs** for all time why can't you dump this data into HDFS or S3(AWS) it will be cheaper and you will have all the features of HDFS available with your data.
Storing all data in Brokers will increase overhead on Zookeeper as well.